# how to rename two files to different name automatically in bash

Tags: bash, loops

I have a problem that I want to know how to do it automatically in bash:
I have 12 folders(0,1,2,3..11), each contain two files like shown below, for example, in folder 1, it contains:

```
4DNFI6E4RZ9H.fastq.gz
4DNFIIN1NES7.fastq.gz
```

and none of the files in the folders share the same name.

I want to create a script that can loop into each of the folders, and rename the files according to the name of the folders, for example for files in folder 1, I want the two files to be renamed to:

```
1_R1.fastq.gz 
1_R2.fastq.gz
```

for files in folder 2, I want the two files to be renamed to:

```
2_R1.fastq.gz
2_R2.fastq.gz
...
```

So how to do it? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in */; do
    c=0
    for file in $dir/*; do
        mv "$file" "${file%/}_R$((++c)).fastq.gz"
    done
done

ls *
```